# foo2.cpp:9: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token

Tags: c++

What is the error in this file? 
I get:

```
foo2.cpp:9: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token
foo2.cpp:9: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
foo2.cpp:9: error: expected ';' before '{' token
```

```
int main(void)
{
  class X {
    int i;
  public:
    X(int ii = 0);
  };

  X::X(int ii) { i = ii; }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm no C++ expert, so maybe this is some feature I've never head about, but I think you have to move the class and method outside of `main()`.

Comment: @minitech the class is ok, it's method that's the problem.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: But if you move the method out of `main()` the class has to follow, right?

Comment: @minitech if you move the method definition outside main, you also have to move the class definition outside, yes.

Comment: Generally you would include your classes in a separate .h file and .cpp file for the methods. But I think Luchian Grigore solved your problem :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, may I ask, **WHY**?

Second, you can't provide an implementation inside a method (including `main`). If you must do this, keep the implementation inline:

```
int main()
{
  class X {
    int i;
  public:
    X(int ii = 0){ i = ii; }
  };
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: many thanks! oops :( I've just started C++ coding so I missed the fact that I had a nested function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest functions in C++. To modify your program, you have two alternatives. You may move your class definition outside of `main`, or you may put your method definition inside the class:

First alternative:

```
class X {
  int i;
public:
  X(int ii = 0);
};

X::X(int ii) { i = ii; }

int main(void)
{
  return 0;
}
```

Second alternative:

```
int main(void)
{
  class X {
    int i;
  public:
    X(int ii = 0) { i = ii; }
  };

  return 0;
}
```